# Rerun failed test on the fly

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mstest

Some of my tests are require a external resources. It is rarely but sometimes the resources gets timeout exception, and makes the test to fail.

I can know if the failure reason is timeout, and I want to let the test second chance to run before it totally fails.

So, is there any way to rerun test after it ends (inside TestCleanup)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You would have to check the timeout within the unit test in question, and implement your retry logic there.

This SOUNDS more complicated than it is. Within your testmethod, you could either write your own retry logic, or use something from Enterprise Library to pass in the call, i.e. if, inside your testmethod you have this:

```
var result = Instance.PossibleTimeoutMethod();
```

then you could do this:

```
[TestMethod, TestCategory("SLOW")]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    // Arrange (this is not real code, just made for example)
    var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy{
        attempts = 3,
        timeBetweenAttempts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
        TimeToWaitBeforeThrowing = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
    }
    ResultType result = null;

    // Act
    retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => result = Instance.PossibleTimeoutMethod());

    // Assert
    result.ShouldEqual(expectedResult);
}
```

Enterprise Library may be overkill for you, but here it is for reference: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vendettamit/retrypolicy-using-microsoft-practices-enterprise-library/